Regex help in Snowflake
I am trying to write a regex that can replace '[', ']' and '].' with '_' and in cases where ']' is the last character it should be replaced with '' but I am struggling to come up with a regex for it that works in all cases because Snowflake does not support lookahead & lookbehind.
My question is, has anyone tried/achieved to do this before? or is it impossible and I should just give up??
Eg:

look_behind[0] --> look_behind_0
look_behind[0]_positive[1] --> look_behind_0_positive_1


Can you show us your attempts

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You have in your two record sample, the datum look_behind[0]_positive[1] which you want converted to look_behind_0_positive_1. You only have one underscore after the 0 - should that be two underscores or should it be only one? This changes the question greatly!

As far as I can see, you have no need to use a regex at all!
Using a search engine, I found that the functions LEFT() (manual for all string functions), RIGHT() and TRANSLATE() have the same signatures (mostly) in Snowflake (1, 2 & 3) as in PostgreSQL. All of the code below is available on the fiddle here.
Populate with your sample data with extra records:
INSERT INTO tab VALUES 
('look_behind[0]'),
('look_behind[0]_positive[1]'),
('No_[brackets]_[at]_end'),      -- two added records for testing
('[]][][_sderfrx÷=/_[]ddf]');

Then, we do this:
--
-- Works where the string <underscore><left-bracket> (_[) OR the string 
-- <right-bracket><underscore> (]_) are to be replaced by two underscores.
--
-- If the last character of the string is <right-bracket> (]), it is replaced
-- by the empty string.
--
-- It is worth noting that the order of the replacements is important as
-- the operations are not commutative - i.e. x R y <> y R x (not necessarily!).
--
--

SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS len,
  TRANSLATE
  (
    CASE
      WHEN (RIGHT(str, 1) = ']') THEN RIGHT(str, -1)
      ELSE str
    END,
    '[]',
    '__'          -- two underscores - one for each bracket (left & right)
  ) AS f_str,
  REGEXP_COUNT
  (
    str,
    '[\[|\]]',
    1,        -- default anyway - not required
    'i'       -- not relevant for non-alpha characters
  ) AS f_str_chars_cnt
FROM
  tab;

Result:
str                       len f_str                 f_str_chars_cnt
look_behind[0]             14 look_behind_0                     2
look_behind[0]_positive[1] 26 look_behind_0__positive_1         4
No_[brackets]_[at]_end     22 No__brackets___at__end            4
[]][][_sderfrx÷=/_[]ddf]   24 _______sderfrx÷=/___ddf           9

You could also do this:
--
-- Works where the string <underscore><left-bracket> (_[) OR the string 
-- <right-bracket><underscore> (]_) are to be replaced by one underscore. 
--
-- If the last character of the string is <right-bracket> (]), it is replaced
-- by the empty string.
--
-- It is worth noting that the order of the replacements is important as
-- the operations are not commutative - i.e. x R y <> y R x (not necessarily!).
--
--


SELECT
  str,
  TRANSLATE
  (
    CASE
      WHEN
        RIGHT  (REPLACE(REPLACE(str, '_[', '_'), ']_', '_'),  1) = ']' THEN 
          LEFT (REPLACE(REPLACE(str, '_[', '_'), ']_', '_'), -1)
        ELSE
          str
      END,
    '[]',
    '__'
  )
FROM 
  tab;

Result (the reader can count the underscores!):
str                         translate
look_behind[0]              look_behind_0
look_behind[0]_positive[1]  look_behind_0_positive_1
No_[brackets]_[at]_end      No__brackets___at__end
[]][][_sderfrx÷=/_[]ddf]    _______sderfrx÷=/__ddf

Regexes are expensive relative to simple string functions. If you really want a regular expression, you can do the following (REGEXP_REPLACE() also has a similar signature in PostgreSQL as in Snowflake):
-- If the last character of the string is <right-bracket> (]), it is replaced
-- by the empty string.
--
-- Works where the string <underscore><left-bracket> (_[) AND the string 
-- <right-bracket><underscore> (]_) are to be replaced by two underscores (__).
--
-- The order of the replacements for the desired outcome in terms of what character/
-- string is replaced first is left up to the reader.
-- 

SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE
  (
    REGEXP_REPLACE
    (
      str, 
      '(.*)]$',  -- replace with pattern 
      '\1'
    ),
    '[\[\]]',
    '_',      
    'g'       -- "global" flag to replace all occurrences
  ) 
FROM
  tab;

Result: same as first (TRANSLATE()) snippet above.
Performance analysis (see end of fiddle):
The entire results of the fiddle aren't included here, but just to see the times is interesting.
TRANSLATE()          - Execution Time: 0.037 ms
REGEXP_REPLACE()     - Execution Time: 0.100 ms
REPLACE(...REPLACE() - Execution Time: 0.027 ms

The time taken for the two string function solutions is roughly 33% of the time taken for the regular expression solution. This is why it's always worth checking to see if an ordinary string function will suffice in cases such as this.
